# On path-components of a subset of the set of all real unipotent matrices

Tags: general-topology, matrices, matrix-calculus, connectedness, unipotent-matrices

> What are the path-components of the following set?
>
> $$P = \{ A \in M_n(\mathbb R) \mid A^k=I_n\}$$

My approach:

Here it's seen that $P$ is not connected as $P_1 = \operatorname {det}^{-1}\{1\}$ and $P_2 =\operatorname {det}^{-1}\{-1\}$ is a seperation of $P$ ; but I think these above two sets are path-connected ; and I think we have to use the Jordan canonical form of those matrices $A .$
But, I am unable to think further .

Also, the matrces $\{A \in M_n(\mathbb C) | A^k =I_n\}$ are diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$, but what about in $\mathbb R ??$

Comment: $P_1$ is not path-connected for $k=n=2$. It is separated into matrices with trace $2$ and $-2$. Similarly for other $n$ and even $k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For even $n$, the my approach hinges on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3420882/513190) of mine. For odd $n$ the solution is as follows.

Note that the possible Jordan canonical forms (over $\mathbb C$) are just the diagonal matrices with $k$-th roots of unity on their diagonals.

Let $\mathcal P = \{A \in M_n(\mathbb R) \mid A^k = I\}.$ Then we have that *$A$ and $B$ lie in the same path-component of $\mathcal P$ if and only if they have the same Jordan canonical form.*

*Proof.*
First, note that all paths in the set of $k$-th roots of unity (in $\mathbb C$) are constant. Since the dependency of a matrix to its eigenvalues is continuous, we have that a path in the set of unipotent matrices cannot include matrices of distinct Jordan canonical forms.

Conversely, suppose $A$ and $B$ have the same Jordan canonical form. Then there exists a real matrix $P$ such that $B = PAP^{-1}$ (this is because whenever real matrices are conjugate over $\mathbb C$ then they are also conjugate over $\mathbb R$).

Suppose $\det P < 0$. Then there exists a real matrix $P'$ (namely $P' = -P$) such that $\det P' > 0$ and $B = P'AP'^{-1}$. 
We can thus assume that $\det P > 0$.

Then we have that $P = e^Q$ for some real matrix $Q$ (since the image of the exponential map is the path-component of the identity in $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$). Then the path $$t \mapsto e^{tQ}Ae^{-tQ}$$
is a path connecting $A$ to $PAP^{-1} = B$ inside $\mathcal P$.

Comment: Sir then what about the odd case ??? Can you provide me some hints ???

Comment: The odd case is solved above, do you mean the even case? I still don't really know, but reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3421300/513190) to my question might be a good place to start.

Comment: O sorry sir, my fault !!