# Characterization of real non-singular matrices whose conjugacy class is path-connected

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3420882/513190), where I asked whether all conjugacy classes of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ were path-connected. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3421300/513190) the following was pointed out.

> The conjugacy class of $A$ is path-connected if and only if $A$ commutes with a matrix of negative determinant.

It is also pointed out that this gives rise to a description of the Jordan normal form of such matrices. But this seems a little unsatisfying, since Jordan normal forms convey little geometric intuition, at least for me.

**Question.** Is there a geometric characterization of matrices $A \in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ whose conjugacy class is path-connected?

Comment: The answer linked is lacking. While it is true that, if the matrix commutes with a matrix of negative determinant, then the class is path-connected, the argument for the converse isn’t enough. Indeed, a topological space which is the reunion of two disjoint path-connected sets can be path-connected. For instance, $\mathbb{R}=(-\infty,0] \cup (0,\infty)$.